# No code coverage when using PowerMock to test final class with static methods Java

Tags: java, testing, junit, powermock, easymock

I am writing a test case for a `final` class that has `static` methods defined inside it.
Now the test case works fine , but when I click on code coverage it says `0%` , although the test case runs fine.

I am using `PowerMock` along with `EasyMock` and using `Junit4`.

My class

```
public class Meals {
    public static String getName(String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            return "bad";
        } else {
            return "good";
        }
    }
}
```

And My test case

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Meals.class)
public class MealsTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMock.mockStatic(Meals.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMeals() {

        EasyMock.expect(Meals.getName(null)).andReturn("bad");
        PowerMock.replayAll();
        assertEquals("bad", Meals.getName(null));
        PowerMock.verifyAll();

    }

}
```

According to me it is because of the annotations `Preparefortest` and `RunWith` , but i'm not sure.

So any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

PowerMock is known to kill code coverage. I think it's because they load custom classes in a special class loader and this code isn't instrumented by the code coverage tools because it's after the fact. I don't think these is a solution to that apart from no using PowerMock.

Do we agree that you test is currently not testing anything? It's just test that PowerMock is working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jacoco + Gradle, you can enable offline-instrumentation by following

```
task instrument(dependsOn: [classes, project.configurations.jacocoAnt]) {
    inputs.files classes.outputs.files
    File outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'instrumentedClasses')
    outputs.dir outputDir
    doFirst {
        project.delete(outputDir)
        ant.taskdef(
                resource: 'org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml',
                classpath: project.configurations.jacocoAnt.asPath,
                uri: 'jacoco'
        )
        def instrumented = false
        if (file(sourceSets.main.java.outputDir).exists()) {
            def instrumentedClassedDir = "${outputDir}/${sourceSets.main.java}"
            print sourceSets.main.java.outputDir
            ant.'jacoco:instrument'(destdir: instrumentedClassedDir) {

                fileset(dir: sourceSets.main.java.outputDir, includes: '**/*.class')
            }
            //Replace the classes dir in the test classpath with the instrumented one
            sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath -= files(sourceSets.main.java.outputDir)
            sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += files(instrumentedClassedDir)
            instrumented = true
        }
        if (instrumented) {
            test.jvmArgs += '-noverify'
        }
    }
}
test {
    dependsOn instrument
    useJUnit()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}
```

Code credits to https://github.com/esdk/g30l0/commit/82af4c9aad50aadc40d940471fe1b934473170c7

This is an open issue
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2429